# why am I getting Object literal may only specify known properties AND Element implicitly has an 'any' type?

Tags: typescript

I must not be understanding how type syntax actually works in typescript... I have the following class:

```
class MyService {
  static _current_state = 'FOO';

  private static readonly STATE_MAPPING: { [ string: number ] : number } = {
    'FOO': 123,
    'BAR': 456,
  };

  static get STATE () : string {
    return MyService._current_state;
  }

  ...etc

  private isValidThreshold (value: number) : boolean {
    return MyService.STATE_MAPPING[LogService.STATE] >= value;
  }

  ...etc
```

I get `error TS2322: Object literal may only specify known properties, and ''FOO'' does not exist in type '{ [string: number]: number; }'.`

and `error TS7015: Element implicitly has an 'any' type because index expression is not of type 'number'.`

What am I doing wrong?

Comment: Would have been less confusing to you if you didn't use `string: number`. One of these is the type of the key, the other just a label.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

TS clearly states that you don't have `FOO` prop in `STATE_MAPPING` and it has only indexer with a number as a key and `FOO` is definitely not a number.

```js
class MyService {
  static _current_state = 'FOO';

  private static readonly STATE_MAPPING: { [ index: string ] : number } = {
    'FOO': 123,
    'BAR': 456,
  };

  static get STATE () : string {
    return MyService._current_state;
  }
}
```

You can play with it [here](https://www.typescriptlang.org/play?noUncheckedIndexedAccess=true&target=99&module=100&noImplicitOverride=true&noPropertyAccessFromIndexSignature=true&exactOptionalPropertyTypes=true#code/MYGwhgzhAECyCeBlApgJwG4EtjOgbwFgAoaaCAFzHO2gH1gBXVVZAO3NoqtwF5oByAGIB5YfwDcxYqQAOqTOm5lK1YNBZgAJgHtWIeNEQAVAIJGAorVgmACjYCSAOQDiALnzQA2tEytNyAA93CnlWAHNoAF1od1YGAFsAIzRoAF9oPkISUgERMXcARgAmAGYAGmkc-gAhEwAlfncAFgBWADYK7NTJIkquVWgw5HJDUwtoAAoAShjlUIisnPVhplY4JDQsHAA6eiYWdk4VZB7SVOJUoA)